# learn c the hard way ex25 confusing about fgetc stdin

Tags: c

I am working on learn c the hard way ex25 by Zed A. Shaw

[ex25](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/master/ex25/ex25.c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "dbg.h"

#define MAX_DATA 100

int read_string(char **out_string, int max_buffer)
{
    *out_string = calloc(1, max_buffer + 1);
    check_mem(*out_string);

    char *result = fgets(*out_string, max_buffer, stdin);
    check(result != NULL, "Input error.");

    return 0;

error:
    if (*out_string) free(*out_string);
    *out_string = NULL;
    return -1;
}

int read_int(int *out_int)
{
    char *input = NULL;
    int rc = read_string(&input, MAX_DATA);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read number.");

    *out_int = atoi(input);

    free(input);
    return 0;

error:
    if (input) free(input);
    return -1;
}

int read_scan(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int i = 0;
    int rc = 0;
    int *out_int = NULL;
    char *out_char = NULL;
    char **out_string = NULL;
    int max_buffer = 0;

    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, fmt);

    for (i = 0; fmt[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (fmt[i] == '%') {
            i++;
            switch (fmt[i]) {
                case '\0':
                    sentinel("Invalid format, you ended with %%.");
                    break;

                case 'd':
                    out_int = va_arg(argp, int *);
                    rc = read_int(out_int);
                    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read int.");
                    break;

                case 'c':
                    out_char = va_arg(argp, char *);
                    *out_char = fgetc(stdin);
                    break;

                case 's':
                    max_buffer = va_arg(argp, int);
                    out_string = va_arg(argp, char **);
                    rc = read_string(out_string, max_buffer);
                    check(rc == 0, "Failed to read string.");
                    break;

                default:
                    sentinel("Invalid format.");
            }
        } else {
            fgetc(stdin);
        }

        check(!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin), "Input error.");
    }

    va_end(argp);
    return 0;

error:
    va_end(argp);
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *first_name = NULL;
    char initial = ' ';
    char *last_name = NULL;
    int age = 0;

    printf("What's your first name? ");
    int rc = read_scan("%s", MAX_DATA, &first_name);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed first name.");

    printf("What's your initial? ");
    rc = read_scan("%c\n", &initial);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed initial.");

    printf("What's your last name? ");
    rc = read_scan("%s", MAX_DATA, &last_name);
    check(rc == 0, "Failed last name.");

    printf("How old are you? ");
    rc = read_scan("%d", &age);

    printf("---- RESULTS ----\n");
    printf("First Name: %s", first_name);
    printf("Initial: '%c'\n", initial);
    printf("Last Name: %s", last_name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

    free(first_name);
    free(last_name);
    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}
```

I am confused about the first parameter in read_scan in [line 109](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/45703363ecabc6cdbc32143965adc32b3cae2b2f/ex25/ex25.c#L109)

The original code works fine. The output:

```
What's your first name? zed
What's your initial? A
What's your last name? shaw
How old are you? 18
---- RESULTS ----
First Name: zed
Initial: 'A'
Last Name: shaw
Age: 18
```

However, if I delete the '\n' in [line 109](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/45703363ecabc6cdbc32143965adc32b3cae2b2f/ex25/ex25.c#L109) `rc = read_scan("%c", &initial);`, it will skip the next question and I cannot figure out.

What I think about the influence of '\n' is that the [for loop](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/45703363ecabc6cdbc32143965adc32b3cae2b2f/ex25/ex25.c#L53) will not go into [line 83](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/45703363ecabc6cdbc32143965adc32b3cae2b2f/ex25/ex25.c#L83) `fgetc(stdin);`

The output will be:

```
What's your first name? zed
What's your initial? A
What's your last name? How old are you? shaw
---- RESULTS ----
First Name: zed
Initial: 'A'
Last Name:
Age: 0
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters in the `"%c\n"` to `read_scan()` mean read and capture one character, and read and discard another character.  You could have an `X` or `@` instead of the `\n` and it would work the same.  When you delete the newline from the format, the newline after the character is left in the input.  Then the next call to `read_scan()` with `"%s"` invokes `fgets()`, which reads up to the next newline, but the next newline is the already in the input stream, so it returns immediately.

Note that if you typed a word instead of an initial, or if you have no middle initial (me!), things go wrong in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the type and size of the format string which `read_scan()` needs to process

```
rc = read_scan("%c\n", &initial);
```

In this case, it's telling `read_scan()` to read (a) any character AND (b) a newline character. If you look at the flow in the function, it checks for "%", if found it increments the counter `i` and then checks the next character in the format string. For line 109, that character is `c`, so the `fgetc()` function is called. This reads a single character from the file descriptor `stdin` and places it into `out_char`. Then the loop continues, and since we're not reading a string, we go to the `else` case on line 82 - which reads another character (which is '\n' for newline). The important difference with the `fgetc` call on line 83 is that we throw away the result.